# How to add tableview on scrollview programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created one tableview programmatically. But I want to enable horizontal scroll for that tableview. So I think I need to add first scrollview programmatically and then on that scrollview I need to add tableview which I have created. Please help me how to do this or correct me if I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do so. `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` and adding one `scrollView` on another will create problem.

`UITableView` already has **horizontal scroll property**(as its super class has). You can use it.

Comment: thanx for reply but i am new to this i-phone application devlopment.Can you please guide me more on this.

Comment: when your tableView width is more than that of screen width than it will autmatically provide you horizontal scrolling. (if directionLock is not enabled).

Comment: By horizontal scroll property, I mean horizontal scroll behavior(by scrollView's nature).